# How to change the value of the Show "No answer" field in general settings?

Tags: limesurvey

On creating a survey I want to change the value of the Show "No answer" field in the tab presentation & navigation under general settings. But this field is disabled its value is "On (Forced by the system administrator)". I can't change the value. How can I change this to off state?

Comment: Just in global settings. You need to be super administrator.

Comment: Is the super admin is the user that is created during installation of the lime survey then I have checked the settings using that user.

Answer (score 4):

The admin user has a setting in the global setting field to set, disable, and allow survey administrators to change the setting according to their preference.

Ask the user with super admin rights to set this value for you.

The steps are :

As system admin

- Navigate to Global settings on the top toolbar.
- Click the presentation tab
- Set the "Show 'no answer' option for non-mandatory questions" to "Survey Admin can choose:
- Save

As the survey admin

- Choose and open the survey
- Select the 'General Settings' option on the second toolbar
- Navigate the the "Presentation and Navigation" tab
- set the 'Show "No answer"' dropdown value to No.

Comment: I have created a user of role Super administrator. Then I have checked  the settings using the user again same result as I mentioned in the question.